# Etymology of 'curvy' to describe the feminine figure

Tags: etymology, word-usage

A term that has been recently  spreading also outside the English speaking world, especially, but not only, in the field of fashion is *curvy*. E.g. [Curvy Convention 2015](http://curvyconvention.co.uk/models-on-the-catwalk-2015/): *Models on the Catwalk*

> The convention will be the ultimate curvy shopping experience…

***[Curvy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/curvy)*** is an adjective that means  *'full of curves'*  whose usage dates back to the beginning of the 20th century ([1902](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=curvy&searchmode=none)), according to Etymonline.

Later in the century, apparently around the 60's (see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=curvy%20women%2Ccurvy%20woman%2Ccurvy%20girl%2Ccurvy%20girls&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccurvy%20women%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurvy%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurvy%20girl%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurvy%20girls%3B%2Cc0)) the term started to be used to refer to women with the following meaning:

> - (informal) of a woman’s figure,  shapely and voluptuous. (ODO)

[image]

Questions:

- When was the term first introduced and in what context (Hollywood movies,  TV shows ,  politics)?
- Was is initially used as a 'neutral' and 'politically correct' alternative to  terms such as *voluptuous*, or to more common but less complimentary terms, like *chubby* and *fat* for instance?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the word euphemism. Was *curvy* originally a euphemism for *fat*, *chubby*, and *plump*, which are generally derogative etc..

Comment: I think *curvy* replaced "big-boned" and "she's a big girl" when referring to women.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - rather then an 'euphemism' my suspect is that there was at one point the  the need of a 'politically correct' term, but who felt the need to use it.

Comment: I don't think PC really came into force before the mid 1980s, and *curvy* is definitely older than that. You should post the Ngram chart (I haven't seen it yet).

Comment: It would take more research to nail down the why and when.  I would look at this in the context of other related terms to see whether one tends to replace another over time. For instance:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=curvy+woman%2Cvoluptuous+woman%2Cshapely+woman%2Chourglass+figure%2Cbusty+woman%2Ccallipygous%2Cbig-busted%2Cwasp-waisted&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3

Comment: Speaking as a mathematician, I see value in using "curvy" as it applies to a large range of shapes, excluding only those with no discernible _inflection points_.  And it seems relatively neutral. Those are also its drawbacks—it cannot replace more specific terms that clarify the nature and location of the inflection points, and the presumed desirability thereof.

Comment: Hmmm.. it appears "plump" has peaked. One might preliminarily postulate that it has passed its prime. Other than that, no clear trend or frontrunner.  On my graph, the only clear trend is that "voluptuous" does not seem to have diminished with the rise of "curvy".  "Voluptuous" did show a significant drop around 1987, but this was quiickly adjusted, and  was not accompanied by a significant rise in any of the other terms tracked.  In both graphs, the total of all tracked terms seems to trend upward in the long view, perhaps indicating an increasing openness about discussing female shape.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - ok, but in ordinary speech, would you say that she (a friend for instance) is 'curvy' or 'voluptuous'?

Comment: @Dan Bron: Apparently it's many others' favorite as well. Adding it to the ngram list. It rivals _voluptuous_.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=curvy+woman%2Cvoluptuous+woman%2Cshapely+woman%2Chourglass+figure%2Cbusty+woman%2Ccallipygous%2CRubenesque%2Cbig-boned+woman%2Cbig-busted%2Cwasp-waisted&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3

Comment: ***Curvy Convention 2015.*** : http://curvyconvention.co.uk/models-on-the-catwalk-2015/

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - which pictures?

Comment: I think something has been glossed over or conflated in the comment thread so far, and we need to explicitly unpack it in order to answer the question appropriately: *curvy* / *voluptuous* has been applied to two distinct types of body; what we want to discuss is the later of these two senses, the euphemistic use for "fat" or "a conventionally unappealing weight", which intentionally borrowed the *connotations* (but not *denotation*) of the earlier uses of these terms, e.g. In noir fiction of the 40s meaning essentially 36-24-36 but expressly *not* overweight (24" waist = flat tummy).

Comment: Uh, women have had curves since ... well, since we climbed down from trees.  As is the the case for many such terms, the words used to describe a "well-proportioned" woman (keeping in mind that the standards for that change fairly quickly) tend to change quite often, as old ones "wear out" and lose their "punch".  Also, the propriety of discussing a woman's figure tends to ebb and flow, so the terminology changes with it.  "Curvy" is an obvious term for a woman who has "curves".  (I don't interpret "curvy" as meaning "plump", but I suspect that "plump" women choose it as a euphemism.)

Comment: Josh61:  two interesting items in your link:  1) the "convention" is a British thing 2) "curvy" is equated with "plus size". Adding "plus size" to ngram, and setting corpus to BrE.  Oops! "curvy woman" does not yet occur in BrE corpus—maybe it jumped the pond recently?  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=curvy+woman%2Cvoluptuous+woman%2Cshapely+woman%2Chourglass+figure%2Cbusty+woman%2Ccallipygous%2CRubenesque%2Cbig-boned+woman%2Cplus+size%2Cplump+woman%2Cbig-busted%2Cwasp-waisted&year_start=1965&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3

Comment: Such a good question, maybe my answer doesn't do it enough justice :( I was hoping someone would have looked into the connection between boat curves and women curves, although  shaunxer found that citation on the spinnaker (sail). Why don't you do a little investigative work, you might uncover something.

Comment: I will, I am anyway more focused on its current usage. I am still under the impression that 'curvy' is now a popular term, also internationally, because of its usage in the fashion business (also in Italy as you know) because it carries connotations (nuances in meaning, orthography, easier spelling etc,) that other terms, like curvaceous for instance, don't. But it is probably just my own impression.

Comment: Rather lame of Etymonline to say 1902, when it's used in a poem published in 1747.

Comment: @PhilMJones - rather lame of you not to link that poem :)

Comment: @Josh61, you're right  - oops! "Below, a bridge across its current bends, / Whose curvy head a steady passage lends".
http://hdl.handle.net/2027/uc1.a0004295614?urlappend=%3Bseq=205

Comment: @PhilMJones you should post a question, ask for the earliest instance of *curvy*, remember to point out etymonline's claim, and link it back to Josh's question :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

“Curvy” used to describe a slim, well-proportioned, woman; however, today it's a euphemism for women whose waist-hip ratio  are more likely to suggest an overweight—or in some extreme cases—a morbidly obese woman.

In recent years, feminists and  tabloids have extolled the virtues of being “curvy” and the so-called “real woman” body, arguing that women need to accept their natural contours and feel proud of their bodies, regardless of their size. On the other hand,  cynics protest that the term *curvy* is being abused and is now a catch-all for any woman who is just the F-word (the term *fat* is considered so derogatory, it's become a taboo word).

### Why Curvy?

I don't think it's possible to pinpoint the date or the reason for a word becoming widespread, but the following excerpt might shed some light.

> Any reference to ‘fat’ is negative. Heather Smith (1989) relates how fear and hatred of  ‘fat’ pervades ‘Western’ cultures. Fat bodies are defined as ‘disgusting’ or ‘diseased’ and fat women are considered to be, or represented as being, asexual, maternal, or sexually desperate. […] Most women are aware that the ‘ideal’ body is unattainable but feel compelled to attempt transformation and consequently develop a punishing self-hating relationship with their bodies.
>
> <sub>*The Illusions of "post-feminism": New Women, Old Myths* (**1995**) By Coppock, Haydon, and Richter</sub>

The excerpt suggests (in my opinion) that the terms *curvy*; *curvaceous*; *shapely*; *voluptuous*, and *plus-size* were selected to boost women's self-esteem and replace the highly-derogatory term *fat*. In the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=curvaceous%20woman%2Ccurvaceous%20blonde%2Ccurvy%20woman%2C%20plus-size%20women&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccurvaceous%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurvaceous%20blonde%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurvy%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplus%20-%20size%20women%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccurvaceous%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurvaceous%20blonde%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurvy%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplus%20-%20size%20women%3B%2Cc1) below, note how the term *curvaceous woman* (blue)  seems to spiral upwards after the 1990s, whereas *curvaceous blonde* (red) saw its maximum peak in the early 1990s.

[image]

Bear in mind that Ngrams are only an indication, and do not truly represent, in any way, shape or size (ha!) speech trends, and when they do it's several years too late. But, I confess, Ngrams are pretty to look at, so here is [another chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=curvaceous%20woman%2Ccurvaceous%20blonde%2Ccurvy%20woman%2Cvoluptuous%20women%2Cshapely%20women&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccurvaceous%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurvaceous%20blonde%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurvy%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvoluptuous%20women%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshapely%20women%3B%2Cc0) comparing the previous terms, (minus *plus-size*)  with the following: *voluptuous women* (blue line) and *shapely women* (red line).

[image]

When did the semantic change take place?  Baxter, and  Cosslett, the authors of *[The Vagenda: A Zero Tolerance Guide to the Media](https://books.google.it/books?id=tVLyAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT32&dq=euphemism%20curvy&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAGoVChMI9b-70_yWyAIVTNYaCh2mUApV#v=onepage&q=euphemism%20curvy&f=false)*  suggest this happened in the early 2000s.

> What's even more perplexing about the use of term such as ‘curvy’ is the fact that by the early noughties, body fascism had become so universal that any woman who *didn't* look like a malnourished size zero was immediately lavished with praise for her ‘body confidence’

### What does “curvy” mean in 2015?

Dr. Robyn Silverman, shortlisted thirteen terms that many American female teenagers have adopted in their every day lexicon: *muffin top*, *teacher's elbow*, *pooch*, *bra bulge*, *cankles*, *back fat*, *stick chick*, *tits on a stick*, *fit chick*, *curvy chick*, *fat chicks*, *midsized fat chicks*, and *supersized fat chicks*.

[image]

<sub>Source: *Good Girls Don't Get Fat* (2010)
 By Robyn Silverman</sub>

So it seems that the term, *curvy*, is still perceived to be less offensive than any of the traditional euphemisms that were in vogue before the 1980s, e.g. *full-figured*, *big-boned*, *matronly*,  and *plump*.

Before the term *curvy* came into vogue, women who had narrow waists and whose bust and hip measurements matched were commonly described as having “**hourglass figures**”

> a few years ago gave quite an impetus to the dress-reform movement by persuading a multitude of women of the necessity for more breathing space ; but fashion has now decreed that the **hourglass figure** is the ideal shape for woman. The National Dressmakers' Association, which recently held a meeting in Chicago, insisted that although a woman may have the shoulders of an athlete, she must have a waist like a wasp, and if she has not such a waist by nature, it is the duty of the dressmaker to produce it by a process akin to that by which the Chinese woman remodels her feet.
>
> <sub>*Good Health*: **1905** - Volume 40 - Page 371</sub>

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hourglass+figure%2C+curvy+woman%2Cshe+had+curves%2C&year_start=1890&year_end=1940&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chourglass%20figure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurvy%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20had%20curves%3B%2Cc0)  seem to confirm this, the following expressions in the English corpus: “hourglass figure” (blue line); “she had curves” (green line);  and “curvy woman” (red line) are compared across the years 1890—1940.

[image]

### The origins of curvy

> FROM time immemorial it has been an axiom of occidental mariners that **both a good woman and a good boat possess plenty of curves in the right places**. Like many another old adage it is founded on sound common sense. There are boats that are weird and there are boats that are wonderful, and it is amazingly seldom that one sees a craft that is both weird *and* wonderful. Conversely, the oriental sailor is a different breed of man. His women are flat and angular, and his boats are monstrous in Western eyes.
>
> *Pacific Motor Boat* - Volume 32 - Page 12 (**1939**)

Could it be that a ship's curved prow or bow reminded sailors of a woman's *curvy* body? It's true that the historical  pronoun for a ship in English is "she", and many sailing vessels were/are given female names, there is also evidence to suggest that in Old English, ships were gendered. In most Indo-European languages with grammatical gender, the word for "ship" is feminine.
As a theory, it's plausible.

Consider also the following   [proverb](https://books.google.it/books?id=EuvqPkAq2bkC&pg=PA390&lpg=PA390&dq=A%20ship%20under%20sail%20%20%20big-bellied%20Woman&source=bl&ots=1VpmZjeGfD&sig=K1sE4_ovd1oqfNyBczaEWC-mpSc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMI9PeY8NajyAIVJ_5yCh0-dgfv#v=onepage&q=A%20ship%20under%20sail%20%20%20big-bellied%20Woman&f=false), dated **1735**,  which Benjamin Franklin is credited as being its author.

> A ship under sail and a big-bellied Woman
>   Are the handsomest two things that can be seen common.

In this case, the billowing sail of a ship is compared to a woman's large curved belly carrying an unborn child.

According to Random House Dictionary, the term *[curvaceous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/curvaceous)* was coined sometime between 1935-1940. The first match  for *curvaceous blonde* I found on Google Books is in 1944, the fact there are no inverted commas surrounding this description implies that readers were already familiar with this form of compliment.

> Kim Kimberly, **curvaceous blonde**, turns in top vocals, and Massey is again spotted. On other numbers needing sax work, Drasnin is spotted with Earl Ziskin. Thruout the set Allen's piano is in there solid.
>
> Source: [Billboard](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kxoEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PT15&lpg=PT15&dq=%22Kim%20Kimberly,%20curvaceous%20blonde%22&source=bl&ots=c5HJnWseqy&sig=dPGN7tn3o4vB7PEOqxGBra9obVg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIn7CB8fKXyAIV6KZyCh3ElwPX#v=onepage&q=%22Kim%20Kimberly%2C%20curvaceous%20blonde%22&f=false) - 21 Oct 1944

Kim Kimberly was Armide Whipple's stage name, a singer who began her career singing in the  Ben Pollack band but opted to leave show business in 1946. I was curious to see whether she was indeed voluptuous or shapely like Marilyn Monroe, so I searched for her image online.

[image]

I doubt she would be classed *curvaceous* or *curvy* nowadays,  she was an attractive blonde vocalist who never made it “big”.

### “Curvy” women in the 1900s

In 1907, 1911, and in 1919 the adjective *curvy* described women who were more “soft”, and very slim rather than voluptuous and big-busted.

> But what a figure she had! Sinuous, supple, rounded, and yet very slight. "She must have the smallest possible bones," Paul said to himself, "because it looks **all curvy and soft**, and yet she is as slender as a gazelle." She was tall, too, though ...
>
> <sub>Source: Three Weeks - Page 22 (**1907**) by Elinor Glyn</sub>

The British novelist Elinor Glyn was the prototype of today's modern liberated and sexually active woman  at the turn of the 20th century

> [Elinor Glyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elinor_Glyn) pioneered risqué, and sometimes erotic, romantic fiction aimed at a female readership, which was radical for its time, though her writing would not be considered scandalous by modern standards. She coined the use of the term "It", which is repeatedly yet erroneously described as a euphemism for sexuality or sex appeal.
>   […] **she had tremendous influence on early 20th-century popular culture** and perhaps on the careers of notable Hollywood stars such as Rudolph Valentino, Gloria Swanson and Clara Bow in particular.

Other examples:

> They are also very fond of sitting down. It is **the graceful, curvy woman** who has a bad time at her dressmaker's  being fitted and fitted and fitted. Personally, I did not own a rag that hadn't cost me hours of weary standing and having pins stuck in me before a mirror. The behabited lady had transformed the glances of her sulky eyes from her boots to me with such a disagreeable ...
>   <sub>*The Claw* - Page 69 (**1911**)</sub>

> Then the bottom dropped out of the world for Ronald; Josie, the awkward little goose he remembered, floated to the front of the stage with something of the gliding snowiness of a swan.
>
> She was **tall and slender but very curvy**, and not with the curviness of a gawky little girl.  Little Josie had been hollow chested and plump stomached. But this Josie was decidedly neither. She was very frail, however—as **lithe** as a budding willow, but terrifyingly pallid.
>
> [*"Momma": And Other Unimportant People*](https://archive.org/stream/mommaandotherun00hughgoog/mommaandotherun00hughgoog_djvu.txt) (**1919**) By Robert Hughes

In less than a hundred years, curvy has changed from Glyn's *curvy and soft*, yet *slender as a gazelle* description in 1907, to [Urban Dictionary's](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=curvy) stark definition in 2006

> Used most commonly in teen magazines as a euphemism for "fat" or "chubby."
>    It works brilliantly as a marketing ploy for these companies, and it keeps from damaging the self-esteem of their overweight American adolescent consumers.
>
> Curvy, in the traditional sense, means having an ample bosom, trim waist, and round butt.
>
> *Tyra Banks, Gisele Bundchen, and Scarlett Johansson are truly curvy. They have meat in all the right places!*

Comment: Wholly admirable answer! I'm surprised you omitted mentioning the competitor, zaftig, which is used almost exclusively to describe women: [zaftig woman,curvy woman,zaftig](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zaftig+woman%2Ccurvy+woman%2Czaftig&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Czaftig%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurvy%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Czaftig%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @JEL It's not a term I'm familiar with, I like Yiddish words but this one has slipped through the nets. However, *hourglass, and *voluptuous* wins hands down https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zaftig+woman%2Ccurvy+woman%2Czaftig%2Chourglass%2C+voluptuous&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Czaftig%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccurvy%20woman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Czaftig%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chourglass%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvoluptuous%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Mari-LouA, just to confirm my distrust of Ngrams, I re-ran @BrianHitchcock's Ngram using "curvy woman,voluptuous woman,shapely woman,hourglass figure,busty woman,callipygian,big-busted,wasp-waisted,zaftig. Those terms seem more likely to draw from pertinent uses ("hourglass" from yours looks like a ringer to me, and "voluptuous" is suspect--they're both used in literature to describe many things unwomanly). Using those terms, "zaftig" comes out slightly ahead of "voluptuous womand", in second and third place respectively. What the fascination with "hourglass figure" is, is beyond me.

Comment: Yes, I'd stopped here to comment and only later saw your comment (worthy of the lady herself) about Mae West under shaunxer's answer.  Looking at the covers of Screen Book Magazine for 1936 (http://tinyurl.com/nh9slta), what pulchritude!

Comment: Gorgeous covers, I agree.

Comment: @JEL but in the Ngrams I posted I have used the terms *voluptuous* and *shapely* connoted with *women*. I could have searched for *she is/was voluptuous* but that would have disregarded any results which included the article "a" and proper nouns; e.g. *Sofia was a voluptuous Italian woman*. Ngrams are useful tools, but they don't tell the whole story, they help support answers though :)

Comment: I found "curvaceous", dated Winter 1941. http://hdl.handle.net/2027/mdp.39015036897885?urlappend=%3Bseq=130

Answer (score 3):

I found an interesting excerpt form the book, *[Movers and Shakers: A Chronology of Words that Shaped Our Age](https://books.google.com/books?id=XXQqCAWcZ8cC&dq=curvaceous%20origin&source=gbs_navlinks_s)*

This is for the word "curvaceous" which seems to be the more popular word when referring to the female form. Anyway, here's the excerpt:

> The originally American colloquialism is characteristic of an era
>   (1930s to 1950s) when large breasts and wide hips were the thing. 
>   1936 Screen Book Magazine: The curvaceous lady [sc. Mae West] receives
>   from Paramount just as many dollars per week for her scenario work as
>   she receives for her acting.

I also looked up that passage taken from Screen Book Magazine to see if I could find any more info and I came across this article: http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/08/mae-west/

It certainly seems that Mae West had a big influence on this word, especially with these excerpts:

> The early life jackets issued during WWII gave the wearer a puffed-up
>   chest and feminine figure, swiftly earning them the moniker ‘Mae
>   West’.

....

> The Oxford Companion to Ships and the Sea also lists a type of
>   spinnaker (a large three-cornered sail) nicknamed the ‘Mae West’
>   thanks to ‘the large swelling curve it took up when filled with wind’.

So although the word "curvy" didn't originate during this time, it certainly appears that Mae West had arguably the largest impact on it's increasing popularity.

Comment: ***Curvaceous***: 
1936, U.S. colloquial, from curve + facetious use of -aceous, Modern Latin botanical suffix meaning "of a certain kind." First recorded reference is to Mae West. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=curvaceous+&searchmode=none

Comment: Aha! So what I'm thinking now is- curvaceous eventually re-merged with the word "curvy" because now-a-days you never see "curvaceous" but "curvy" instead. So the real origin of the "curvy" we use today comes from "curvaceous" which began in 1936.

Comment: [Mae West](http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large/1-mae-west-1892-1980-granger.jpg), the woman who didn't discover curves but uncovered them.

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't clear, I apologize. But Mae West was quoted as saying [I didn't discover curves, I only uncovered them](https://www.google.it/search?q=Mae+West+quotes+curvy&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CCIQsARqFQoTCJzqpdDPoMgCFcHVGgodNPMAtg&biw=1366&bih=677#tbm=isch&q=%22Mae+West%22+quotes+curves)